# Jupyter Notebook in VsCode insiders shows duplicate output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using VS-code insiders for my jupyter notebook, it was working properly until recently it started giving me duplicate output in the notebook, I have tried to stop the conda server and even closed and reloaded the notebook, nothing seems to work, if anyone can help me with the same.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to re-install the previous version of Jupyter extension from vs-code and check the results, again?

Comment: I have , I even reinstalled VScode again

Comment: The bug not related to vs-code itself. Have you tried to install an older version of Jupyter from vs-code extension?

Comment: Are you using insider builds? I have the same problem, I think maybe is a recent bug hmm

Comment: @Vibhor -Have you tried using VSCode (not VSCode insider) to perform this process?

Comment: It works on Vscode , and it seems like a recent bug on Vscode insiders build

Comment: @UselesssCat yes it is coming after i updated Vscode insiders recently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using VS Code Insiders the UI for notebooks is actually provided by VS Code itself (this is a new feature so it's only being rolled out in insiders) as opposed to the extension. This new VS Code Notebook UI is still pretty early so there are occasionally issues with it. Your issue looks like this one here, which looks to have been resolve just a few days ago. Looks like updating to the newest build of VS Code - Insiders (not the Python or Jupyter extension) should fix the issue for you.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112337